# Como acrescento um input type="radio" em um formulário?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Como acrescento um input type="radio" em um formulário para o resultado ir para outras paginas?
 E quando eu for editar o formulário a escolha do radio continuar salva?

Comment: Pode explicar melhor sua dúvida? Não está dando pra entender.

Answer (score 1):

Algo como isso? Porém isso seria no html, você gostaria de criar uma função em PHP que montasse esses campos (Desculpe não entendi muito bem sua proposta)?

```
<form action="#" method="POST">
    <input type="radio" name="cor" value="vermelho"  <?= isset($_POST['cor']) && $_POST['cor'] === 'vermelho'  ? 'checked' : '' ?> >Vermelho
    <input type="radio" name="cor" value="azul" <?= isset($_POST['cor']) && $_POST['cor'] === 'azul' ? 'checked' : '' ?> >Azul
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

Então depois você recupera assim -> `$_POST['cor'];`

Comment: não está memorizando a opção quando vou editalo

Comment: é o botão ja tenho

Comment: Você quer que ele já esteja selecionado quando o usuário voltar a tela é isso? Utilize inline if para dar checked ou não no input; ou deixe um checked por padrão;

Comment: agora quando vo editar esta sempre salvo o vermelho

Comment: quero que apareça o qual eu salvar

Comment: Substitua a variável $_POST['cor'], pela desejada. Acabei de editar um exemplo para você.

Comment: quando eu saio da pagina e volto não memoriza. Acho que tem que ir para msql nao?

Comment: Bom, você pode jogar na sessão ou algo assim dependendo do que você pretende com ele... caso você quer que seja gravado como algo padrão para todos os usuários, melhor guardar no banco então.